# AS3 split function

Tags: actionscript-3

I have the following code

```
function _getTime(msgStr){
       var theStr:int = (int)msgStr.split(' ');
       return theStr;
     }
```

And am recieving the following error.

```
Expecting Semicolon Before msgStr
```

Not sure what the problem is

I am trying to convert this PHP function. Found online to use split but it does not seem to work.

```
function _getTime($msgStr){
    return (int) strtok($msgStr,' ');
}
```

Comment: What is that int supposed to do?

Comment: Supposed to turn turn the split text into an int.

Comment: james, with split you are creating an array. You can't convert it to an int.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please see what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: I can tell you that if you build your function this way `function _getTime(msgStr){var theStr:Array = msgStr.split(' ');return theStr;}` you can return an array, so if you have `var a = _getTime("I am a lazy guy");` with `a[0]`, you get "I", with `a[1]` "am", and so on. If you want to convert this to a number you can do `Number(a[0])` and, if at index 0 you have "1" it will convert it to 1.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're implementing this function? Or give an example of what 'msgStr' would expect to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Type casting in ActionScript works like this:

```
int (1.15)
```

instead of

```
(int) 1.15
```

2) AsTheWormTurns is right: `split()` returns an array of strings - you cannot cast it to `int`.  If I understand the PHP function correctly, it returns only the first entry of that array as `int`.  So what you are looking for should be:

```
function _getTime ( msgStr : String ) : int {
    var arr : Array = msgStr.split (' ');
    var theStr : int = parseInt( arr[0] );
    return theStr;
}
```

or even simpler, since parseInt() parses everything until the first non-numerical character:

```
function _getTime (msgStr:String) : int {
    return parseInt (msgStr);
}
```